# How to load options.html in jQuery-colorbox, upon a context menu item click?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, colorbox

I am adding 'options' to my chrome extension. I wonder how can I user [colorbox](http://colorpowered.com/colorbox/)) from background page or content scripts, when context menu item is clicked.

I have spent more than a day on this without success. Is there anybody who has done this? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

While you certainly can't use this from a background page, since colorbox shows UI, you have a few options from a content script:

1. You could do an XHR to fetch the contents of the background page ([chrome.extension.getURL](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/extension.html#method-getURL) may be helpful) and write the contents of the result into the colorbox.
2. You could embed an `<iframe src="/path/to/options.html">` in your colorbox.

I'm assuming you know how to bind JS functions to context menus? Just in case, the [contextMenu docs](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/contextMenus.html#method-create).

Have you tried either of these options?

Comment: Thanks Boris, I am aware of your two pints, I can populate colorbox on options page. But the same doesn't work on background page. I am using `$.fn.colorbox({...});` for colorbox popup. Is it because the document is background page, I must use it on the current tab window? Any thoughts?